# Activity starts with delay when calling startActivity from background thread and the main thread being blocked

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm trying to block the main thread and show user a dialog activity (running in another `android:process`) for a yes/no decision. After user's click on yes or no, the dialog activity finishes and the main thread resumes. Please note that blocking the main thread is *required* for my project.

Starting the dialog:

```
private boolean getUserDecision() {
    DialogRunnable dialogRunnable = new DialogRunnable();
    Thread thread = new Thread(dialogRunnable);
    thread.start();
    while (thread.isAlive()) {
        try {
            // block the thread until user enters his decision
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return dialogRunnable.decision;
}
```

And `DialogRunnable`:

```
class DialogRunnable extends Runnable {
    public boolean decision;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        Intent intent = /* intent for launching the dialog */
        intent.setResultMessenger(new Messenger(new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
                decision = msg.arg1 == 1;
            }
        }));
        startActivity(intent);
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

#### Unexpected Behavior

If `getUserDecision` gets called on the main thread, the dialog starts after a noticeable delay (~ 1s), but calling that method from a background thread starts the dialog immediately. Why?

Comment: "Please note that blocking the main thread is required for my project" -- why do you think this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm actually developing a system framework for AOSP, which hooks certain binder calls. It's not a regular app.

Comment: You can try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: If you block the main thread, Android will throw an ANR.

Comment: @DavidWasser There's no ANR, everything works fine. The only problem is the aforementioned delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the Activity Manager Service [waiting](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java#943) for the app's `onPause` to complete. And since the main thread is blocked, ActivityManagerService waits for [500ms](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java#103) and gives up and then launches the next activity.